# Least Impossible Subset Sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, arithmetic-combinatorics

Given a set ***A*** which contains natural numbers from 1 to N. Also given another set ***B*** which contains ***p*** natural numbers between 1 to N. We have to find out the least sum of subset which is not possible in the set ***A***-***B***
One way to do so is to apply subset sum problem on set ***A***-***B***. Is there any faster method which uses set ***B*** to determine the least subset sum that is not possible?

Comment: [Linked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089727/minimum-sum-that-cannot-be-obtained-from-the-1-n-with-some-missing-numbers)